# Haskell's DataKinds and relation of values, types and kinds

Tags: haskell, types, type-kinds

Say I have this:

```
data Animal = Dog | Cat
:t Dog
Dog :: Animal
```

Fair enough.

```
:k Dog

<interactive>:1:1:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Dog’
    A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?
```

Wasn't expecting that to work since Dog is a value, not a type. You cannot get a kind of a value, only a kind of a type, right?

But, if I do this:

```
:set -XDataKinds
data Animal = Dog | Cat
:k Dog
Dog :: Animal
```

What does this mean that you can get a kind of a value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope. You can only get the kinds of types. What `-XDataKinds` does is take data declarations and give them *two* meanings: first, it declares a new type and some corresponding value constructors; and second, it declares a new *kind* and some corresponding type constructors. So with `DataKinds` on, the following declaration:

```
data Animal = Dog | Cat
```

creates *all* of the following:

- type `Animal`
- value `Dog` of type `Animal`
- value `Cat` of type `Animal`
- kind `Animal`
- type `Dog` of kind `Animal`
- type `Cat` of kind `Animal`

The three namespaces -- term-level, type-level, and kind-level -- are completely disjoint. In case `DataKinds` would define a new type in two different ways, you can use a prefix `'` to indicate that you want the lifted version. Thus:

```
> :set -XDataKinds
> data Animal = Animal
> :k Animal
Animal :: *
> :k 'Animal
'Animal :: Animal
```

Comment: Some of this is set to change in GHC 8.0, where types and kinds will be merged internally.